# How does the Orbeon Portlet map URLs?

Tags: orbeon

I've been using eXist REST services by accessing resource URLs such as /exist/rest/db/orbeon/app/form/data to run xqueries.

Running 4.1.0.2013040182144-PE on Liferay 6.1.1-CE

The URLs work with FR and FR Proxy Portlet, but not with FR Full Portlet. I need to use the Full Portlet to be able to use Liferay Roles for visibility/read-only constraints.

This is what I get in orbeon.log:

```
2013-05-28 18:29:52,851 INFO  PageFlowControllerProcessor  - not found {controller: "oxf:/page-flow-portlet.xml", method: "POST", path: "/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr/parkers/cars/data", resource: "/apps/exist/page-flow.xml"}
2013-05-28 18:29:52,936 INFO  ProcessorService  - /exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr/parkers/cars/data - Timing: 121
2013-05-28 18:29:53,009 ERROR XFormsServer  - xforms-submit-error - setting throwable {throwable: "
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Fatal error: The element type "img" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</img>".                              |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|file:///exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr/parkers/cars/data        |   1| 611|                                                  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException                                                                  |
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try setting the following property:

    `<property as="xs:anyURI"
      name="oxf.url-rewriting.service.base-uri"
      value="http://localhost:8080/orbeon"/>`

(Adjust to point to your local Orbeon Forms WAR.)

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for this. It's still the same situation with that property set, though. I'll probably fully qualify the resource URI for now; I would, though, appreciate what was happening as it gives me a better idea of what's going on underneath. For instance, is there a way for the portlet landing page to be a Form Runner form summary?

Comment: That you can do with the [Form Runner Portlet](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/form-runner-proxy-portlet-guide). Is that a possibility for you?

Comment: As for URL rewriting, it is always a *very* tricky thing and I don't know the answer on top of my mind unfortunately. If you have a reproducible case which we can look at, we can enter an issue.

Comment: Can I use Liferay Roles for visibility/read-only constraints with the Proxy Portlet?

Comment: No yet, see https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/946